# Restringir rutas mediante rol

Tags: laravel

Yo tengo una **tabla Roles con 2 registros Administrador(id=1) y Empleado(id=2)**.
Mi tabla Users se relaciona con la tabla Roles por lo tanto cada usuario tiene un campo llamado idrol donde logicamente guardo la **ID del rol** (**el numerit**o).
Como puedo limitar al rol Empleado para que no pueda acceder a las rutas del Administrador?

Lo que no entiendo es la función del handle, es decir verifica que cumple la condición de idrol 2(empleado) pero igualmente le deja pasar dando totalmente acceso a todo(al menos eso entiendo yo).

Tengo lo siguiente.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->idrol==2){
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');

    }
```

Y lo tengo puesto asi en el web.php, Administrador:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['Administrador']],function(){
             Route::get('/main', function () {
                 return view('contenido/contenido');
             })->name('main');

            //---------PERSONAS---------//
            Route::get('/persona', 'PersonaController@index');

            Route::get('/persona/rol', 'PersonaController@rol');
            Route::get('/persona/rolDesact', 'PersonaController@rolDesact');
            Route::post('/persona/registrar','PersonaController@store');
            Route::put('/persona/actualizar','PersonaController@update');

            //---------PERMISOS---------//
            Route::get('/permiso','PermisoController@index');
            Route::post('/permiso/registrar','PermisoController@store');
            Route::put('/permiso/actualizar','PermisoController@update');
            Route::put('/permiso/eliminar','PermisoController@eliminar');

            //------ROLES-------//
            Route::get('/rol','RolController@index');

            //---------AUSENCIAS---------//
            Route::get('/ausencia','AusenciaController@index');
            Route::post('/ausencia/registrar','AusenciaController@store');
            Route::put('/ausencia/actualizar','AusenciaController@update');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarPermiso','AusenciaController@filtrarPermiso');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarInicio','AusenciaController@filtrarInicio');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarFinal','AusenciaController@filtrarFinal');


            //---------AUSENCIAS-ADMIN---------//
            Route::get('/ausencia/admin','AusenciaAdminController@indexAdmin');



            //---------REGISTROS---------//
            Route::get('/registro','RegistroController@index');
            Route::post('/registro/registrar','RegistroController@store');
            Route::put('/registro/actualizar','RegistroController@update');
            Route::put('/registro/eliminar', 'RegistroController@eliminar');


            //---------REGISTROS-ADMIN---------//
            //Muestra registros de todos los empleados, asignar a los usuarios admin
            Route::get('/registro/admin','RegistroAdminController@indexAdmin');



            //----REGSITRSO-ADMIN-USERS-DESACTVIADOS----//
            //Muestra los regisotrs de los empleados desactivados, se usa en el vue Registroantiguosempleados
            Route::get('/registro/adminDesact','RegistroAdminController@indexAdminDesactivados');



        });
```

Rutas del Empleado

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['Empleado']],function(){

             Route::get('/main', function () {
                 return view('contenido/contenido');
             })->name('main');

            Route::get('/registro','RegistroController@index');
            Route::post('/registro/registrar','RegistroController@store');
            Route::put('/registro/actualizar','RegistroController@update');
            Route::put('/registro/eliminar', 'RegistroController@eliminar');

            //MIS AUSENCIAS
            Route::get('/ausencia','AusenciaController@index');
            Route::post('/ausencia/registrar','AusenciaController@store');
            Route::put('/ausencia/actualizar','AusenciaController@update');

        });
```

Comment: Cómo se llama el middleware donde tenés esa función handle()?

Comment: Es la de Empleado, la de Administrador tengo lo mismo pero cambiando el idrol que seria 1

Comment: Usa JsonWebToken, creas un middleware que valide el rol del usuario y lo mencionas en las rutas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te paso un ejemplo de un *middleware* que solo deja pasar staff empleados. Crealo en `app/Http/Middleware/SoloEmpleados.php`:

```
    class soloEmpleados
    {

       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
           if (! $request->user()-> esEmpleado()) {
              abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
           }

        return $next($request);
      }
    }
```

Luego `esEmpleado()` es un metodo del modelo `app/User.php` que podría ser algo así:

```
public function esEmpleado()
{
    return $this->idrol === 'EMPLEADO'
}
```

Registras el *middleware* en `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],

    'empleado' => [
        'auth:api',
        soloEmpleados::class,
    ],
];
```

Y en las rutas lo usas de esta forma (`routes/web.php`):

```
Route::middleware('empleado')->group(function () {...
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que explicaras donde agregar dichos códigos para que la respuesta en si mejore su calidad y facilidad de uso

Comment: @Aprendiz, he añadido los archivos y sus rutas relativas.

Comment: En el web.php el Route de middleware empleado lo pones dentro del middleware auth cierto? La función "esempleado()" que tienes dentro del modelo User no hace falta si yo pillo la variable del Auth no? Tal y como yo lo tengo en mi handle empleado supongo que no me hace falta ninguna funcion. en mi modelo User.

Comment: Valee me funcionó, solo hay una cosa que no entiendo, es que si una ruta esta en Administrador y también está en Empleado, solo me deja visualizarlo cuándo estoy como empleado, sabes por que pasa esto?No se si es un error de configuración mio o Laravel funciona así aunque no le veo mucho sentido.

Comment: Es posible  (no lo he comprobado) que si tienes una ruta con dos middleware que se contradigan, el primero que se define es el que se aplica. Si tienes Route::group(['middleware'=>['Administrador','Empleado']],function(){... se va a pillar Administrador. De todos modos no tendría sentido tener un middleware para solo admin y solo empleados. Usa siempre el menos restrictivo.